# TYPO3 News Section Database Tables

Tags: database, typo3, tx-news

I am using News System extension to display all the news articles.

I would like to know in which table in the database are these news articles stored ?
Can I add data directly into the backend MySQL tables for these news articles ?

I actually tried adding data into 'news_domain_model_news' table in my database, but the changes are not reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

`tx_news_domain_model_news` is the correct table, but adding the data there is not sufficient for TYPO3. You also need to add that data to the `TCA` (Table configuration array) and to the Database definition, and make EXT:news aware of the new field

The most simple way to do so is this:

1. Create a new Extension using the "extension_builder"-Extension (creates the mentioned entries in the TCA and the database definition files)
2. Create a class "Tx__Domain_Model_News" in your new extension that contains the new fields and setters + getters for them (Use the naming conventions, otherwise it won't work!)
3. Add a file "Resources/Private/extend-news.txt" to your new extension, containing "Domain/Model/News" as its only content.

That should be it. Here is a link to the extension manual, describing the process:

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Tutorial/ExtendingNews/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the records directly in the database, but be aware that there are multiple caches in TYPO3 CMS.

Therefore clear the caches after you finished editing the data.